# TCL get index of current element in string with reasonable overhead

Tags: string, tcl

I've read a file into a string and split the elements by newline char

```
if {[file exists $inputFile] == 1} {
    set fpI [open $inputFile r]
    set input [read $fpI]
    set lines [split $input "\n"]
    close $fpI
} else {
    return "File does not exsist"
}
```

Now I would like to go over the entire file, line by line and when I get a match for certain conditions I want to store the line #, which is , in fact, the element number in the $lines string. How can I get the line number without using an additional variable and without running search each time (high overhead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the simplest mechanism is to keep your own line counter. Though a `foreach` does have an internal index counter, it isn't exposed to scripts at all.

```
set lineNumber 0
foreach line $lines {
    incr lineNumber
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set fp [open inputfile r]
while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
    incr line_num
    if {$line eq "SOMETEXT"} {
        break
    }
}
close $fp
puts "line_num : $line_num"
```